# Rails building an API without duplicating code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a PeopleController which my users can access when they login to my app

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController    
  def create
    # stuff here
  end
end
```

And then my boss tells me we need an API, so we go with something like this in addition to what we already have:

```
class API::V1::PeopleController < ApplicationController    
  def create
    # stuff here
  end    
end
```

Is it unusual to have code duplication like this? Should I be looking for a way to DRY this up? I don't mind a bit of duplication but it looks like I'm going to have to make 99% of our existing codebase available through the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your boss is asking of you is to implement versioning. Versioning is quite useful particularly to ensure backward compatibility of API endpoints.

In such situations, the duplication of code might turn out to be a necessary evil since you wouldn't want updated code in later versions that alter functionality to cause issues in earlier versions.

There are gems such as [Versionist](https://github.com/bploetz/versionist) that help you out with the process of versioning so that much of the process of duplicating the code and adding the required namespacing is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks. All the answers are really helpful, this is the best. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The "Rails way" is one controller, which knows how to respond to JSON and HTML. This is why you have `respond_to`/`respond_with`/etc.

There's no reason to spin off a second API controller unless you actually *want* to have your API and non-API controllers diverge.

If you simply want to route `/api/v1/people` to the same place as `/people`, that's a job for your `config/routes.rb`. If you want to add/change behavior in the API *on top* of the regular controller's behavior, then you can inherit your API controller from your non-API controller:

```
class API::V1::PeopleController < ::PeopleController
```

Comment: There is one catch, it is hard to version the API.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, all the answers given have helped me with this difficult decision, and as @Acacia mentions, I will probably need to version the API. cheers though, the respond_to technique comes in handy a lot of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If its basic crud, you can have the same controller respond to html(for your website) and xml or json format(for your api)

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController    
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml {render :xml => @people}
      format.html {redirect_to people_path(@people)}
    end
  end
end
```

You can adjust your route based on the format if you want your routes to look different for api

Comment: Thanks for this, I had considered using respond_to with a format, it's a nice fallback, and I like the fact that rails has these nuances.

Answer (score 1):

If you API might change over the lifetime the application and requires versioning then you need two different controllers.

However, if you API is maybe for the mobile application do not have multiple users and wont require frequent re-visioning then have a simple controllers and simply user `respond_with` and `respond_to`.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that the duplication is worth it as I need to version the API. Cheers.